# Can ScalaTest detect timeout without synchronization calls (like in an infinite loop?)

Tags: scala, freeze, scalatest

In a following code the test called `sleep` fails gracefully, while the test `freeze` causes the testing to never end.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.concurrent.TimeLimitedTests
import org.scalatest.time.SpanSugar._
import scala.language.postfixOps

class MainTest extends FunSuite with TimeLimitedTests {
  def timeLimit = 1 second

  test("sleep") {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }

  test("unintentional freeze") {
    var i = 100
    var j = 0
    while (i>0) {
      i += 1 // a bug: should be j += 1
      i -= 1
    }
  }

}
```

I understand this because of the way how `TimeLimitedTests` uses `ThreadInterruptor` to abort timeouted tests. Is there some other way how can ScalaTest detect and fail such code? If not, is there some common practice how avoid or detect this type of bugs in the tested code?

When I run tests manually in the IDE, I can abort them manually and those with infinite loops will be marked as not started, but I am concerned that when this happens in a code committed, the Jenkins build process is frozen as a result, requiring a manual abort on the build server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your example is artificial. In real life even infinite loops has invokes thread sleeping at least for millisecond: `Thread.sleep(1)`. And in such case `interrupt` will properly work.

But assume there are no sleeping. So you need to override `defaultInterrruptor`  to kill thread in more "reliable" way.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalatest.concurrent.{Interruptor, TimeLimitedTests, ThreadInterruptor, Timeouts}
import org.scalatest.time.SpanSugar._

import scala.language.postfixOps

class MainTest extends FunSuite with TimeLimitedTests {

  override val defaultTestInterruptor: Interruptor = new Interruptor {
    override def apply(testThread: Thread): Unit = {
      println("Kindly die")
      testThread.stop() // deprecated. unsafe. do not use
    }
  }

  def timeLimit = 1 second


  test("sleep") {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }

  test("freeze") {
    while (true) {}
  }


}
```

Comment: "In real life even infinite loops" What I mean is an infinite loop caused by a program bug. It just happened to me one algorithm looped infinitely due to float rounding errors. How can testing framework help me catching this type of bugs?

Comment: If anyone else is going to use this: be aware the testing framework thread is terminated by this interruptor, and no more tests will be executed after the timeouted test failure. This is probably a good thing, as the state of anything used by the thread at the time of its killing could be corrupt.