# scalatest Flatspec: Timeout for entire class

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

With the scalatest Flatspec and the TimeLimits trait I can set a timeout for a line of code like so:

```
import org.scalatest.time.SpanSugar._
import org.scalatest.concurrent.TimeLimits
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class MyTestClass extends Flatspec with TimeLimits {
  "My thread" must "complete on time" in { 
    failAfter(100 millis) { infiniteLoop() }
    // I have also tried cancelAfter
  }
}
```

This should fail due to a timeout. However, when I run this test in Intellij it just runs forever.

Furthermore, I do not want to have to rewrite the timeout for every method, instead I would like to configure it once for the entire class. The [PatienceConfig](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.8/org/scalatest/concurrent/PatienceConfiguration.html) claims to do that, but it does not seem to do anything. The test is still runs forever.

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.time.{Millis, Span}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.{Eventually, IntegrationPatience}

class MyTestClass extends Flatspec with Eventually with IntegrationPatience {
 implicit val defaultPatience = PatienceConfig(timeout=Span(100, Millis))

 "My thread" must "complete on time" in { 
   inifiniteLoop()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I looked for a solution myself. came a cross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742779/can-scalatest-detect-timeout-without-synchronization-calls-like-in-an-infinite) answer, it worked for me.
I am using flatspec, added the trait TimeLimitedTests

```
with TimeLimitedTests
```

then inside the code I wrote my limit for each of the tests `val timeLimit: Span = Span(2000, Millis)`
which is defined by the trait (we are overriding it).

Finally it didn't work until I overriden the interrupter as suggested by Rumoku in the referenced answer by

```
override val defaultTestInterruptor: Interruptor = new Interruptor {
override def apply(testThread: Thread): Unit = {
  println("Kindly die")
  testThread.stop() // deprecated. unsafe. do not use
}}
```

I hope this helps