# How to set a timeout for Async suite in Scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest, asynctest

Consider the following unit test example:

```scala
class MySpec extends AsyncFlatSpec {

  "this" should "fail after some timeout" in {
    val resultFuture: Future[_] = Promise().future
    
    for (result <- resultFuture) yield {
      assert(result == ???) // some assertions
      assert(result == ???) // some assertions
      assert(result == ???) // some assertions
    }
  }
}
```

### The problem

If `resultFuture` **never** completes the test suite never finishes either.
As I understand it's due to the way how `SerialExecutionContext` is implemented.

### The question

Is there any "nice" way how to setup a timeout for this kind of tests, so that if the future isn't complete the test just fails, instead of blocking the entire test suite for eternity?

---

### UPDATE and clarification

While solutions https://stackoverflow.com/a/65746143/96766 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65749840/96766 (posted by @matthias-berndt and @tomer-shetah) work for the case of blocked thread, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Let me make an important clarification to the question. In my case the future isn't eventually complete, but **never** complete.  For example, when a `Future` is obtained from the `Promise` that is never resolved (nobody calls `success` nor `failure` on it). In that case the proposed solutions still block infinitely.

Is there a way to work this around for `AsyncSpec` without resorting to using a real pool-based execution context and `Await`-ing on the future?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but almost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742779/can-scalatest-detect-timeout-without-synchronization-calls-like-in-an-infinite

Answer (score 4):

Use `eventually` from `scalatest`

1. extends `Eventually`
2. Use the following code to set up timeout and interval for checking

```
 import scala.concurrent.duration._
 eventually(timeout(1 minutes), interval(5 seconds)) {
    resultFuture.futureValue shouldBe ???
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. I setup 2 sec timeout, but the test remains blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AsyncTimeLimitedTests` trait.

https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.0/org/scalatest/concurrent/AsyncTimeLimitedTests.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trait [`TimeLimits`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.2/org/scalatest/concurrent/TimeLimits$.html). For example, you can have a test class:

```scala
class MySpec extends AsyncFlatSpec with TimeLimits {

  "this" should "fail" in {
    failAfter(2.seconds) {
      val resultFuture: Future[_] = Future {
        Thread.sleep(3000)
      }

      assert(true)
    }
  }

  "this" should "pass" in {
    failAfter(2.seconds) {
      val resultFuture: Future[_] = Future {
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      }

      assert(true)
    }
  }
}
```